# Why broker charge me for BORROW fees when I have a long unsettled position as well to counter the short in the same account

Tags: options, fees, interactive-brokers

The only reason why I put it here is to find out whether I am a victim or just ignorant of the way brokers deal with option positions that were exercised. Whether I am a victim or just ignorant will depend on your answer posted here.

The facts are:

1. I had a 2 SHORT QS Option at 75 which was exercised against me on the 23 Dec 00.45 AM and I later exercised my 2 LONG QS Option at 70 on 23 Dec 9.31 AM. The broker charged me Borrow Fee for 24-27 Dec for $1102, which means instead of getting $1000 profit I turn this into a loss of $102 plus comm.

My question:

2. Since both long and short options were exercised on the same day one at 45 mins on 23 Dec and the later at 9.31 am on the same day, how can there be a SHORT POSITION in the stocks since both are net-off in my account ?

The answer I got from my broker and this is the point that I want to clarify.

3. The response I got from IB was that the initial exercise at 45 mins on 23 Dec was actually on 22 Dec (not 23 as I alleged). They refused to show me how they got 22 Dec.

This is my explanation to my Broker in reply.

4.Even if the short call and long call were exercised on different dates 22 and 23 Dec respectively, IB can only charge me for the SHORT position for one day and not from 24-27 Dec by ignoring my long call position was not there.

5. My Broker ignored my answer and insisted the dates are correct and therefore I was charged to borrow shares that needed to satisfy the short position on exercised. So I am lost as I do not know whether the broker is correct and they can do this by ignoring my long call position after exercised or there is something else.

I hope I have explained this clearly now and this is not an opinion as some suggested to cut my question down. This is how I responded to the broker and their silence is the reason why I am here, hoping to get clarity as to the way options long and short are settled.

Comment: You asked this same question [here](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/137025/how-options-are-settled-can-be-an-eye-opener-and-i-hope-i-can-get-some-answers).  Commenters asked several questions which you ignored.  What has changed?

Comment: Whomever is voting to close this question as duplicate should vote to reopen the other, as it has been elaborated since closed.